# Hibernate does not delete child entity second time with orphanRemoval

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Code is shared in github. Situation looks like this I have opened Transaction. I create ExampleEntity and ExampleChildEntity. They are connected by bidirectional reference. Steps which i take:

```
ExampleEntity.setChild(child);
saveAndFlush() // insert goes to db
ExampleEntity.setChild(null)
saveAndFlush() // delete goes to db
ExampleEntity.setChild(child)
saveAndFlush() // insert goes to db
ExampleEntity.setChild(null)
saveAndFlush() // no delete here
```

I tagged hibernate because I think it's Hibernate problem (I'm using spring data jpa) because when I switch JPA provider to EclipseLink everything goes well. Am I doing something wrong or it's a bug? I have tried setting child reference to parent to null but this does not work also. Example project:
https://github.com/pustypawel/delete-twice-bug

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: In following example no. But when transaction is commited I have child object associated with parent what is wrong. My production code was more complicated I had unique index on one of child fields and after commit i was getting UniqueKeyViolationException

Comment: In this example, the value returned by `saveAndFlush()` is ignored. Can you replace all the lines with:
`exampleEntity = exampleRepository.saveAndFlush(exampleEntity);` and see if you still have the problem ?

Comment: Yes i have tried this also, still not working